# Is there any event bubbling which passes event from parent View to children or vise versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native-table-component which I want to override each row and put a customized cell inside the row. I have a checkbox inside the cell for each row. I want to catch the checkbox "onPress" event on my row so I would be able to change the style of row to "selected". Or in another scenario I would like to catch the row "onPress" event so I can check the checkbox.

I have tried to make it work by recording the touched item in my state inside the onPress event of TouchableOpacity `this.setState({TouchedItem:index});`
then when I wanted to change the style of my row in `TableWrapper` I could not do it because it will remove my striped table styling. So I am looking for a way to catch the event (of clicking a row and checking the checkbox belonging to that row) and also style the row different from other rows if it is selected.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Table, TableWrapper, Row, Cell, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';

import {  Checkbox } from 'galio-framework';


export default class MyTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['Head', 'Head2', 'Head3','Head4'],
      selectedItems: [],
      checked: false,
      TouchedItem: -1
    }
  }



  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const tableData = this.props.tableData;
    const element = (data, index) => (
      <Checkbox label="" 
                  initialValue={this.state.checked}
                  onChange={initialValue => {
                    if(!initialValue)
                      {
                        var index = this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(data);
                        if (index > -1) {
                          this.state.selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                      }
                    }
                    else this.state.selectedItems.push(data);
                  }}

      />
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
      <Table borderStyle={{borderColor: 'transparent'}} >
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          {
            tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={()=>{
                 this.setState({TouchedItem:index});
                 //this.style = styles.rowSelected;

                }}>
                   <TableWrapper key={index} style={

                    index%2==0 ? styles.row:styles.rowStripe  
                     //this.state.TouchedItem==index ? styles.rowSelected:styles.rowSelected

                     }>
                   {
                      rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
                      <Cell key={cellIndex} data={cellIndex === 3 ? element(cellData, index) : cellData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
                      ))
                   }
                  </TableWrapper>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))
            //index%2==0 ? styles.row:styles.rowStripe
          }
        </Table>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.processOrder()}>
                 <View style={styles.btn}>
                 <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
                 </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </View> 
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#808F97' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: 'darkgray' },
  text: { margin: 6 },
  row: { flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8' },
  rowStripe: {flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'lightgray'},
  rowSelected:{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'red'},
  btn: { width: 80, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'orange',  borderRadius: 2,textAlign:"center" },
  btnText: { textAlign: 'center', color: '#fff' }
});
```

The optimal output would be that when i click on a row the checkbox would be selected. and the row style changes when it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I did not used event bubbling in react, but what you can do is event delegation. when you click parent component all of its decendants will listen to this event. and when adding event handler on Row component and you have checkbox inside of it change the color of row and also check the checkbox.

[pretty good explanation of what is event delegation](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983)

Comment: Thank you. could you review my current code and see if i can solve my issue?